# Not able to display dialog properly

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am working on an application in which I am invoking a dialog from my fragment on a button click but my problem is that when I click on a button and then dialog appears but it display in dull colour. And when I again click on dialog then its background changes to white colour. So, I just want to know why it is happening like this.

**Code to invoke dialog from fragment on button click**

```
       sms = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.sms);
    sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!admin_id.equals("0") && status.equals("A")) {
                DialogSMS dialogSMS = new DialogSMS(getActivity(), getContext());
                dialogSMS.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.disable_click), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    });
```

**Dialog Code**

```
    public class DialogSMS extends Dialog {

Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String MY_PREF = "pref";
public static final String IS_SMS_SUBSCRIBE = "sms_status";
EditText etPostalCode;
EditText phoneNumber;
Dialog d;


public DialogSMS(Activity a, Context context) {
    super(a);
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.app_sms_dialog_msg);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            SessionManager session = new SessionManager(context);

            if (session.isSmsSubscribed()) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.app_sms_unsubscribe);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        unSubscribeSMS();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();


            } else {
                d = new Dialog(getContext());
                d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_select_sms);
                etPostalCode = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.etPostalCode);
                phoneNumber = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);


                Button btnSend = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
               d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

                btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        String mobile = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
                        String postalCode = etPostalCode.getText().toString();

                        validateFields(mobile, postalCode);

                        //subscribeSMS(postalCode, mobile);
                        // d.cancel();
                    }
                });
                d.show();
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.app_close_dialog_msg_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

And now screenshot link for dialog when first appears

**Dark screenshot while open pop-up :**

[image]

**White dialog when click on dialog again :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know why it is happening like this

Here,

```
DialogSMS dialogSMS = new DialogSMS(getActivity(), getContext());
dialogSMS.show();
```

Will show a dialog and inside of DialogSMS you are also creating AlertDialog and showing it again,

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.app_sms_dialog_msg);
--------------------------
alertDialog.show();
```

When you are clicking on dialog its canceling on of dialogs.

You actually do not need to create AlertDialog inside DialogSMS.

**If you need AlertDialog then why you are showing Dialog?**

*This might help you - *
Just bring your if-else condition inside

> sms.setOnClickListener

and show your desire AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel()`